# How to export table in website to EXCEL with Handsontable

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have a question, Now i am using the Handsontable this plugin to create the table in HTML, which is same like with excel to change the content, add the row and so on.

but my problem is How can I export this changed Table to excel.

Need your help

Comment: It has been suggested to include this feature in Handsontable - the official place to vote for this feature request is http://feathub.com/handsontable/handsontable/+51

Answer (score 5):

You have got two ways to solve this problem -

- On save make an AJAX request to the server with all the data. And use something like Apache POI to create an Excel as documented below -

  [Save JQuery Handsontable to an excel file on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353239/save-jquery-handsontable-to-an-excel-file-on-server)
- Save into Excel from jQuery -
  Create a button for export and on click it will do the following :

> ```
> $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
>     window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
>     e.preventDefault();
> });
> ```

Comment: This assumes excel is installed on the clients machine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=dvData]').html()));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but...

You can easily copy & paste from handsontable into the excel sheet.