# Import from CSV into HandsOnTable and Export to CSV from HandsOnTable

Tags: handsontable

I am using http://handsontable.com/ as one of the widgets for showing prices for my project, I could not find export and import from CSV feature in their API or FAQ.
Has anyone implemented or know about it ?

Comment: Here is nice answer about downloading data as .csv
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353239/save-jquery-handsontable-to-an-excel-file-on-server

Answer (score 1):

Yup, that comment links you to the explanation on how to do it, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/5q9du3rg/2/) is my implementation of it for anyone that wants to just reuse code. There are a few enhancements beyond the basic CSV exporting like the escaping of spaces and special characters, as well as apostrophes. It also sets the column headers if they exist so remove that line if you don't have column headers.

The relevant code assuming you have a button with id=export-csv:

```
function parseRow(infoArray, index, csvContent) {
    var sizeData = _.size(hot1.getData());
    if (index < sizeData - 1) {
        dataString = "";
        _.each(infoArray, function(col, i) {
            dataString += _.contains(col, ",") ? "\"" + col + "\"" : col;
            dataString += i < _.size(infoArray) - 1 ? "," : "";
        })

        csvContent += index < sizeData - 2 ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
    }
    return csvContent;
}

/**
 * Export to CSV button
 */
var exportCsv = $("#export-csv")[0];
if (exportCsv) {
    Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(exportCsv, "mouseup", function(e) {
        exportCsv.blur(); // jquery ui hackfix
        var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
        csvContent = parseRow(colHeaders, 0, csvContent);  // comment this out to remove column headers
        _.each(hot1.getData(), function(infoArray, index) {
            csvContent = parseRow(infoArray, index, csvContent);
        });
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", $("h1").text() + ".csv");
        link.click();
    })
}
```

Hope it helps!