# Export as excel from handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am using handsontable plugin for generate the data as excel format. This is done.

I need to export that data as excel and download.

Is there feature available in handsontable?

If not, How can i achieve this? Here, Handsontable data is different in table format

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a feature yet, it's coming in the Pro version next month. In the meantime, there's [this stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163272/import-from-csv-into-handsontable-and-export-to-csv-from-handsontable) with a solution you could implement. You want to parse the data object from handsontable and then export that string to csv the normal JS way.

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/5q9du3rg/2/) in case you don't want to follow the link, with the relevant code:

```
function parseRow(infoArray, index, csvContent) {
    var sizeData = _.size(hot1.getData());
    if (index < sizeData - 1) {
        dataString = "";
        _.each(infoArray, function(col, i) {
            dataString += _.contains(col, ",") ? "\"" + col + "\"" : col;
            dataString += i < _.size(infoArray) - 1 ? "," : "";
        })

        csvContent += index < sizeData - 2 ? dataString + "\n" : dataString;
    }
    return csvContent;
}

/**
 * Export to CSV button
 */
var exportCsv = $("#export-csv")[0];
if (exportCsv) {
    Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(exportCsv, "mouseup", function(e) {
        exportCsv.blur(); // jquery ui hackfix
        var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
        csvContent = parseRow(colHeaders, 0, csvContent);  // comment this out to remove column headers
        _.each(hot1.getData(), function(infoArray, index) {
            csvContent = parseRow(infoArray, index, csvContent);
        });
        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
        link.setAttribute("download", $("h1").text() + ".csv");
        link.click();
    })
}
```

Comment: I have defined colHeaders inside the handsontable. How can i assign to outside

Comment: Well, you could define it outside, then assign it inside the handsontable.

Answer (score 0):

use the exportFile plugin in handsometable

```
// Mind that CSV exports contain only raw data, and don't include formulas, styling, or formatting information.
let table = new Handsontable(container, options)
// access to exportFile plugin instance
const exportPlugin = table.getPlugin('exportFile');
// export as a string
// exportPlugin.exportAsString('csv');
// export as a blob object
// exportPlugin.exportAsBlob('csv');
// export to downloadable file (named: MyFile.csv)
exportPlugin.downloadFile('csv', {
 bom: true,
 columnDelimiter: ',',
 columnHeaders: false,
 rowHeaders:false,
 exportHiddenColumns: true,
 exportHiddenRows: true,
 fileExtension: 'csv',
 filename: 'Excel-[YYYY]-[MM]-[DD]',
 mimeType: 'text/csv',
 rowDelimiter: '\r\n',
});
```